# What's going on with my objects?

Tags: error, object-mode

My object is not rotating properly  it prefers to go around my object  rather than being turned around. I don't know how it explain this properly  here is a video https://kapwi.ng/c/KhShHYD8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some time I relished that  you can just export and import your file and the object will act good as new.

Answer (score 2):

You have the pivot point set to 3D cursor.  If you go to the topbar in the center area there's a drop down menu that looks like this when it is clicked on.

[image: pivot point drop down]

Switch it to Bounding Box Center to get the behavior you seem to want.

Comment: It's still not working now the object wont move nor will it rotate.

Comment: Please add your blend file to your question so I can take a look.  (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: I am not sure how to export the blender file out of blender with out converting it

Comment: Just save it as a blender .blend file and follow the instructions in my comment using that file.

Comment: The blender file is not appearing in either file explorer nor blend- exchange

Comment: but i think i found another way of fixing my problem.